# JPA Entity depends on independent entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity, persistence

I have two entities, Post and Picture.
I want to keep Picture as independent as possible. Post is suppose to have a Picture, but it's not mandatory. Right now the entities look like this.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pictures")
public class Picture implements Comparable<Picture> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String file;
    //getters and setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
public class Post implements Comparable<Post> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    //some extra fields

    private Picture picture;
    //getters and setters
}
```

The problem is that I don't know what am I suppose to annotate the picture field to make the connection. 
I tried annotating it with @OneToOne and @MapsId (based on a guide from Vlad Mihalcea) but when I try to save the Post entity with a null picture field I get an error like this

```
org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property [com.acme.Post.picture]
```

What is the correct way to fix this? Thank you

Comment: No need for mapsId, just use `OneToOne`

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem!